# django allauth- connecting a user with Fb when a previous user hasn't logged out

Tags: django-allauth

Im using django-allauth for facebook connect (with js_sdk). It works fine for a user. Now consider the following scenario:
1. User A is logged in through Fb
2. User B logs user A out of Fb on the machine and logs himself in.
3. User B then tries to login with fb on my website (user A didnt log out)

This either gives a fb dialog error that "user A has logged out" or it takes me to /accounts/facebook/login/token (in case of existing user) and /accounts/social/connections saying that "you can log in through any of the third party accounts -> User A or User B (in case of a new user)

How do I deal with this scenario, I want that user B should seamlessly log in through fb (even if user A didn't log out).

Answer (score 0):

Up to 0.11.1 accounts were implicitly connected when you logged in using a social account while a user was already logged in. Therefore, your scenario could not be handled properly. In current master this has been addressed -- the resulting default flows now match your expectations.